# Create User login and changing values without using database?

Tags: php

I have a simple website, it's written in php, where there is a values that i have to change from time to time.

To change values i need to login over ftp, open the file and change the values right now.

Because the website is very simple it would be very stupid to create a database just for one username and 5 values.

Is there a way that i can make login system where i would change values on the page and somehow save the changes inside php file without having to make mysql database.

The username and password i will store lets say in config.php file and the values that i need to change i will store in values.php file so values are like now

```
$value1 = '22';
$value2 = '42';
$value3 = '52';
```

so i can login on a page and change that values somehow?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you could save them to a text file and then read them from there

Comment: are you the only user or are there other users? you can save them in $_SESSION

Comment: I am the only user who will use login.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, You can hold values inside any file and simply use:

```
file_get_contents()
file_put_contents()
```